# jquery: how to maintain change in div after user clicks out of div

Tags: jquery

I'd like to keep the last clicked div blue when user clicks a non colorbox class div area. Can this be done with Jquery?

```
$('body').on("click", function(e) {
    $(".colorbox").css('border', '2px solid red');
    $(e.target).closest(".colorbox").css('border', '2px solid blue');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74pzJ/28/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the simplest way would be to attach the handler to the class elements instead of body

```
$('.colorbox').on("click", function(e) {
    $(".colorbox").css('border', '2px solid red');
    $(e.target).closest(".colorbox").css('border', '2px solid blue');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/74pzJ/30/)